# Sent JSON parameter is null in WCF Service method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I want to update a list of confirmations to a server and I use ajax from jQuery.

The problem is that I send the data ( looked that up in Fiddler ) but the service doesn't get that list.

The parameters of the web method are a string and a list. The token is correct but the list is null.

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/teamplay/externalclientrestservice.svc/UpdateConfirmationListforAttender?accessToken=" + accessToken,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    data: '{"accessToken": ' + JSON.stringify(accessToken) + ', "list": ' + JSON.stringify(confirmationList) + ' }'
}).done(function (receivedList)
    {
    alert("Änderungen wurden erfolgreich übernommen");
    return receivedList;
}).fail(function ()
    {
    alert("Etwas ist schief gegangen. Bitte später erneut versuchen.");
});
```

WebMethod:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UpdateConfirmationListforAttender?accesstoken={accessToken}")]
    List<AppointmentConfirmationListItem> UpdateConfirmationListforAttender(string accessToken, List<AppointmentConfirmationListItem> list);
```

In Fiddler I see the list, stringified from JSON, and the accessToken.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not specifying the list in the URI template

Answer (score 0):

I am a novice to json but I experienced similar issue.

I am looking at it from the server side, (REST WCF).

The "solution" I have found was to add the method name in the beginning of your json string.

In your case my suggested json string should be:

> { "UpdateConfirmationListforAttender" : {"accessToken": ' + JSON.stringify(accessToken) + ', "list": ' +
>   JSON.stringify(confirmationList) + ' }
>   }

I am also still searching for a more "generic" solution so my WCF can get the parameters without explicitly having to inject the method name in my client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your UriTemplate to this

```
UriTemplate = "UpdateConfirmationListforAttender/{accessToken}/{list}")]
```

And then remove the `data:` section from your Ajax call and update the URL to this

```
url: "http://localhost:8000/teamplay/externalclientrestservice.svc/
      UpdateConfirmationListforAttender/JSON.stringify(accessToken)/JSON.stringify(confirmationList)
```